# SAX parser not calling start element

Tags: java, xml-parsing, sax, saxparser

I am tring to execute below code but my SAX parser is not calling the startElement method.

Below is my code:

```
package getTableStructure;

import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import getTableStructure.DBdetails;

public class InformaticaObjectParser {
//H:/Eclipse_Workspace/GWM_SHARED_DEFINITION.XML
//H:/Eclipse_Workspace/InformaticaTableStruct/
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    if (args.length == 2){
        System.out.println(args[1]);
        File opDir = new File(args[1].trim());
        if (opDir.exists() && opDir.isDirectory()){
            try {
                SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
                System.out.println("Parser object created");
                MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
                System.out.println(handler);
                saxParser.parse(new File(args[0]), handler);
                String outputDir = args[1].trim(); 
                System.out.println("I am here");
                List<DBdetails> TableList = handler.getEmpList();
                for(DBdetails db : TableList){
                    System.out.println("Table list from XML: " + TableList);
                    //BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new     FileWriter("H:/Eclipse_Workspace/TableStruct/" + tableName + ".csv"));
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter( outputDir + db.getName().trim()+"."+db.getSource().trim()+".csv"));
                        for (String k : db.dbdetail.keySet() ){
                        out.write(k+","+db.dbdetail.get(k));
                        out.newLine();
                        }
                        out.close();
                    }
                } 
                catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e)     {
                    e.getMessage();
                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("2 arguments");
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(" Number of arguments should be 2");
        }
    }
}
```

MY Handler:

```
package getTableStructure;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import getTableStructure.DBdetails;

public class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private List<DBdetails> sourceList = null;
private DBdetails table = null;
public List<DBdetails> getEmpList() {
    return sourceList;
}
boolean bSource = false;
boolean bName = false;

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    System.out.println("In MyHandler");
    System.out.println(qName);
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("SOURCE")) {
        table = new DBdetails();
        String NAME = attributes.getValue("DBDNAME");
        String DbName = attributes.getValue("NAME");
        table.setName(NAME.trim());
        table.setSource(DbName.trim());
        if (sourceList == null)
            sourceList = new ArrayList<>();
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("DBDNAME")) {
        bName = true;
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("NAME")) {
        bSource = true;
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("SOURCEFIELD")) {
        String details = (attributes.getValue("DATATYPE").trim()+","+attributes.getValue("PRECISION").trim()+","+attributes.getValue("SCALE").trim());
        this.table.dbdetail.put(attributes.getValue("NAME").trim(),
                details);
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("SOURCE")) {
        sourceList.add(table);
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    if (bName) {
        table.setName(new String(ch, start, length));
        bName = false;
    } else if (bSource) {
        table.setSource(new String(ch, start, length));
        bSource = false;
    }
}
```

}

Below is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE POWERMART SYSTEM "powrmart.dtd">
<POWERMART CREATION_DATE="06/01/2015 11:44:43" REPOSITORY_VERSION="182.91">
<REPOSITORY NAME="PB_DEV02" VERSION="182" CODEPAGE="Latin1" DATABASETYPE="Sybase">
<FOLDER NAME="PB_DEFINITIONS" GROUP="" OWNER="E466701" SHARED="SHARED" DESCRIPTION="Place all PB source/target definitions here and use shortcuts for them in other PB_* folders." PERMISSIONS="rwx---rwx" UUID="6c90f1e5-b619-48fd-8ee1-5b0b136947ea">
    <SOURCE BUSINESSNAME ="" DATABASETYPE ="Sybase" DBDNAME ="database" DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="table_name" OBJECTVERSION ="1" OWNERNAME ="dbo" VERSIONNUMBER ="1">
        <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="varchar" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="1" FIELDPROPERTY ="0" FIELDTYPE ="ELEMITEM" HIDDEN ="NO" KEYTYPE ="PRIMARY KEY" LENGTH ="0" LEVEL ="0" NAME ="Col1" NULLABLE ="NOTNULL" OCCURS ="0" OFFSET ="0" PHYSICALLENGTH ="8" PHYSICALOFFSET ="0" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="8" SCALE ="0" USAGE_FLAGS =""/>
        <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="varchar" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="2" FIELDPROPERTY ="0" FIELDTYPE ="ELEMITEM" HIDDEN ="NO" KEYTYPE ="NOT A KEY" LENGTH ="0" LEVEL ="0" NAME ="col2" NULLABLE ="NULL" OCCURS ="0" OFFSET ="0" PHYSICALLENGTH ="254" PHYSICALOFFSET ="8" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="254" SCALE ="0" USAGE_FLAGS =""/>
    </SOURCE>
    ..
    ..
    ..
</FOLDER>
</REPOSITORY>
</POWERMART>
```

It was working perfect couple of months ago when I wrote this project but when I opened it now and trying to run the **InformaticaObjectParser**, it is not calling the start element method in **MyHandler** and the programming exists without giving any error.

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Thanks

Comment: You didn't post the code of MyHandler.

Comment: Oops my bad. I added it now. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Please indent your code. It's very hard to read.

Comment: Do you have the XML code to post? Maybe there is a misspelling in the XML or case sensitivity at work...

Comment: try to override the fatalError, error, warning methods to see if there is an error in your document

Comment: @MauricePerry: How can I do that ?

Comment: @Novice see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Guys thanks for your time. I got it. It is because of below line in xml.

```
<!DOCTYPE POWERMART SYSTEM "powrmart.dtd">
```

When I removed it, the code worked. I am not sure about the reason for it. Can somebody put some light on it?

Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

try to override the fatalError, error, warning methods to see if there is an error in your document

```
public class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {
...

    @Override
    public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new SAXException(e.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new SAXException(e.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void warning(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        LOG.log(Level.WARNING, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make it work without removing DOCTYPE from xml. Simply add entity resolver which resolves dtd to empty document as shows below:

```
saxParser.getXMLReader().setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver(){
    public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId,String systemId){
        return new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]));
    }
});
```